# I cant understand how to rotate triangles in java

Tags: java, loops

I am utterly confused. I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer, I just need any help at all. I know most of it is wrong... a lot of it is copied and pasted then I tried to figure it out for myself but I just can't. thanks.
Here's the prompt:

> The following methods print three triangles of different shapes. Add 9 more methods named
>   `drawTri1R90()`, `drawTri1R180()`, `drawTri1R270()`,
>   `drawTri2R90()`, `drawTri2R180()`, `drawTri2R270()`,
>   `drawTri3R90()`, `drawTri3R180()`, and `drawTri3R270()`
>   that will draw 3 more sets of triangles obtained after rotating the original ones 90, 180, and 270 degrees to the right.

AND here's what I have so far,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JaredLainhart_1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size;
        System.out.println("Enter a size:");
        size = in.nextInt();
        Triangle T = new Triangle();
        T.setTriangle(size);
        T.drawTri1();
        T.drawTri2();
        T.drawTri3();
        T.drawTri1R90();
        T.drawTri1R180();
        T.drawTri1R270();
        T.drawTri2R90();
        T.drawTri2R180();
        T.drawTri2R270();
        T.drawTri3R90();
        T.drawTri3R180();
        T.drawTri3R270();
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

class Triangle {
    int n;

    void setTriangle(int nn) {
        n = nn;
    }

    void drawTri1() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri2() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri3() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i-1; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri1R90(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri1R180(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri1R270(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri2R90(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }    
    }

    void drawTri2R180(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }    
    }

    void drawTri2R270(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }    
    }

    void drawTri3R90(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void drawTri3R180(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println();
        }    
    }

    void drawTri3R270(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)    
                System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2*i; j++)
                System.out.println("*");
              System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break it down into parts. First get the triangle printing correctly. Then try to rotate it. It will save you a lot of headache. Also, do you mind adding expected output?

Comment: just to help a little, you don't have to write the code over and over. make 1 method that returns a triangle rotated 90 degrees, then you can use that method multiple times to get 180, and 270 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I always get confused with these 2D problems, too: say drawing plus scaling plus rotating plus coloring, etc. So, what I do is to *reduce the complexity to just one place*, and then add each functionality over it.

I mean: Can you draw **one** single triangle? (Of corse you can, because you have the `drawTri1` method completely disclosed). Well, then create a method to do it, as use it as a basis. But do not draw out to System.out, but to a char array instead:

```
public char[][] fillCanvas(int n)
{
    char[][] canvas=new char[n][]
    for (int row=...)
    {
        canvas[row]=new char[n]
        for (int col=...)
        {
            canvas[row][col]=...
        }
    }
    return canvas;
}
```

Then, code another method to print the array out to System.out, which shall receive as parameters the bounds of each dimension of the canvas:

```
private void printCanvas(char[][] canvas, int fromRow, int toRow, int stepRow, int fromCol, int toCol, int stepCol)
{
    for (int row=fromRow;row!=toRow;row+=stepRow)
        for (int col=fromCol;col!=toCol;col+=stepCol)
            System.out.print(...)
        System.out.println()
}
```

And now you can code any number of methods to rotate the canvas, each one of them will have just to call the `printCanvas` method with the proper parameters:

```
public void printCanvasRotated0(char[][] canvas)
{
    int fromRow=0;
    int toRow=canvas.length-1;
    int stepRow=1;
    int fromCol=0;
    int toCol=canvas.length-1;
    int stepCol=1;
    printCanvas(canvas, fromRow, toRow, stepRow, fromCol, toCol, stepCol);
}
```

The main advantage of this design is to **decouple** the parts of the program between them: Now you can code several methods to print different kinds of shapes (triangles, rectangles, etc), but the method `printCanvas` is still usable for any canvas entered to, so you can cobine them.

Note: Remember that in Java the arrays positions always go from 0 to n-1.